# Sending key stroke to front application in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I was wondering would this be hard to do; I have a barcode reader for my isight (mac webcam) (evoBarcode). At the moment, the program reads the barcode fine and adds it to a text field at the side of the application. Event when in the background, the application continues to run and read barcodes which is fine.

I was wondering, is it easy to send the result from this (I have already located the exact variable where the barcode is caught) to the front application as a keystroke? (the front application being textEdit or something.

I've tried searching around for a bit and found CGRemoteOperation, but havn't found a great lot of resources or examples on it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: found this which works:

        CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)52, true);
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
        CFRelease(e);

But any idea how to change that "(CGKeyCode)52" into a string and send multiple characters?

Comment: FWIW, getting the value into the copy/paste clipboard is pretty simple. If the app you're sending the events to requires additional input anyway (like pressing enter) it might be good enough. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the reader behaviour another option could be to implement a service menu item. That way you don't mess with the clipboard.